# List loaded config files at Emacs start up?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, dot-emacs

**Background**:
I modularised the init.el file into several files and tried to load them one by one from init.el.
Each file has a:

```
(provide 'xxx)
```

at the end and I use:

```
(require 'xxx)
```

to load them.

(before I used load-library to load them, but recent I learned the *require* command will only load them if they are not loaded.)

Then some wired behaviour appears.
I'm not sure if this is the problem of not loading the library in the right order or of not loading certain file.

**So the question is:**

How can I see which file are loaded by the *require* command? (In the 'Message' buffer, I can see files loaded by 'load-libarry', but not by 'require')

Comment: Why not focus on "**Then some wired behaviour appears**"?  Describe the underlying problem (in detail) that you really want to fix, or edit your question to eliminate the part about the weird behavior so as not to confuse the audience.  In general, it is one question per thread.  You can put `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the beginning of your `.emacs` or `init.el` to receive more detailed debugging information -- the debugger readout is what most of the forum participants will be interested in seeing to help troubleshoot the underling issue.

Answer (score 5):

You might inspect the variable `load-history`.

Comment: Evaluating `(mapconcat 'car (reverse load-history) "\n")` may clarify the overall load sequence for you. See abo-abo's answer for looking at `require`d features specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at `featurep` function and `features` variable: each time a `provide` statement is encountered, the `features` variable is updated.

Comment: how to find that variable?

Comment: M-: calls eval-expression

Comment: X.Arthur: If you want to inspect the `features` variable manually/interactively, you just use `C-h v features RET`. (You can also use `M-: features RET` as mentioned, but with the default output settings your features list will probably be truncated using that approach.)